# Removing all colour from a file, making it a vector

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, background, background-removal, image-trace

just had a question about removing all background from an image traced file. If ever someone sends through an image which has words (like the one attached) or if it's got closed off sections, the background remains - when I try to remove it by selecting that specific part and deleting it, it does disappear but also removes the hole which was meant to be there. Similarly if I choose the colour fill and change it to applying a none (/), the same thing happens and the gap disappears. Just wondering if there is a way of getting rid of the filled colour while still retaining the artwork?

The happens with PSD, PND, JPEG files, not illustator files. I work at a printing company so the artwork some customers send is really hard to fully raterise the image, gaps and all?

Very sorry if this doesn't make sense [image: example of what happens]

Comment: Try selecting all and ungrouping and then delete all the pink shapes

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image trace mode to Black and White, and change the threshold setting to remove the background completely.

For example, the original is a colour raster image (above), but the trace is black and white (below). I also set the "Ignore White" option, which should just trace the black text.

[image]